# i want to redirect any action come to my application like this way

Tags: c#, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

```
 [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpPut]
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Gateway2(string Subdomain, string Resource)
        {
           

            // Create an HttpClient and make the request to the API
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(Resource), Subdomain);

            if (this.Request.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in this.Request.Headers)
                {
                    httpRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            if (Request.Parameters != null)
            {
                httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Parameters), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }

            var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

            // Return the response from the API to the user
            var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Ok(responseContent);
        }
```

write getway web api for get post delete  in c# where give input traget subdomain , target method, orginal HttpRequest (with type HttpRequest in c#)
the method will redirect orginal  to target request by using subdomain and method traget
then return the repose with any type

Comment: in this code Request.Parameters it doesn't work with type httprequest

Comment: What's your  `Subdomain` looks like? An uri ? Or ? `new HttpRequestMessage()` need a uri parameter.